# Bootstrap Modal isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to load modal when the windows show up but the only thing I see is the backdrop the content isn't visible. I'm also tryin to use Session Storage.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

      // Start
      // sessionStorage.getItem('key');
      if (sessionStorage.getItem("story") !== 'true') {
        // sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value'); pair
        sessionStorage.setItem("story", "true");
        // Calling the bootstrap modal
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
      }
      // End

      // Do not include the code below, it is just for the 'Reset Session' button in the viewport.
      // This is same as closing the browser tab.
      $('#reset-session').on('click',function(){
        sessionStorage.setItem('story','');
      });
    });
```

```html
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: i suggest you place your code **after** the bootstrap library

Comment: Can you create a snippet that demonstrates the problem?  You currently have some html without the required css and a bunch of irrelevant js.

Comment: @madalinivascu there is no error showing up in console.

Comment: @madalinivascu The backdrop shows, so Bootstrap must be loaded.

Comment: @freedomn-m I edited the post that's the only thing show up when the page load.

Comment: There's something else affecting it as the code you have given us so far works perfectly.... http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/aq9Laaew/77013/

Comment: You may be using some custom css for your modal which makes it's elements disappear?

Comment: Use the developer tools in your browser to inspect the modal dialog elements.  They should identify where in css things are being hidden.

Comment: @ClaudiusDan you are a genius! I forgot that I used custom css before. Thanks mate that fixes the problem! <3

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/0fd9e81v/1/) a working example.
Make sure you've [loaded Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) correctly by using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**EDIT** - Code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Calling the bootstrap modal
  $("#myModal").modal('show');
  
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Answers *must* be self-contained.  Sure, add a link to a working example (if it can't run in a snippet, which an example of a bootstrap modal can), but if you don't include *all the code* to answer the question then it's not a valid answer.

Comment: @Archer I've added the code snippet in the answer, I wasn't aware I could link to external resources in the snippet :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<head>


<body>
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
  dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" > 
</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Start
  // sessionStorage.getItem('key');
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("story") !== 'true') {
    // sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value'); pair
    sessionStorage.setItem("story", "true");
    // Calling the bootstrap modal
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
  }
  // End

  // Do not include the code below, it is just for the 'Reset Session' button in the 
  viewport.
  // This is same as closing the browser tab.
  $('#reset-session').on('click',function(){
    sessionStorage.setItem('story','');
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to load all three js files first before using modal method otherwise it will throw an error